# How do I let some readers view draft versions of items without allowing them to edit

Tags: 2010, permissions, draft

We have a requirement where we would like to give some of our users the ability to view pending versions of the items in a particular list (not document library) to give feedback. We don't want pending items to be visible to everyone that has read permission on the list however. That means that we would have to give these reviewers permission to either edit or approve; which is something that we do not want them to be able to do.

Assuming these reviewers are in a SharePoint group, is there a way to let them view pending versions while preventing them from doing anything else?

Comment: you can use document workspace maybe ?

Comment: Looks interesting, but unless I'm missing something this is for documents and not for generic list items.

Comment: yes, this applies to documents, so is the draft feature. Did yuo pending instead of draft ?

Comment: You are correct. Seems it is called "pending" for regular list items. I'll edit the question to reflect that. In the versioning settings for the list the appropriate section is called "Draft Item Security" and deals with "Who should see draft items in this list".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check this:
http://cregan.wordpress.com/2008/04/16/web-content-management-allow-reviewers-to-see-drafts-and-nothing-else/

Comment: its the correct answer but it would be helpful to include the general steps to do this in the answer itself in case the link ever goes down.

Comment: This solution is exactly the closest thing that I could come up with using "out of the box" settings. However, it still allows the reviewer to edit the item, even though they can't publish it. I'm trying to find out if I can prevent them from even doing that.

Answer (score 1):

The above solution still provides edit permission to the user. The better solution which i found was :

https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Specify-who-can-view-drafts-c3bfc744-c4a4-4691-b506-42b338312c21

By using above solution, no change in user permission is needed. It is just an document library settings change.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create new permission levels. For ex. I have a permsision level "create/edit but not delete items". Create a permission level "Approve only" and check the appropriate permissions using the matrix in https://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sharepointforum.nl%2FDownloads%2FSharePoint%2520Permissions%2520Matrix.xlsx&ei=WrYTVcb_KOnKygPppoKgBw&usg=AFQjCNFUadcUfsdi_IXuP0yGb74I4BTRgA&sig2=vYTxEJAhMN638tp2X7zeYA  . For permisson levels, you can read https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/How-to-create-and-edit-Permission-Levels-53c86040-07fa-4ea7-bc55-34ee96b437fe?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB

Afterwards, create a workflow on item changed, so if the item is in "pending" status, change the permissions, i.e.

a) remove any permissions from the "My contribute" group

b) Give the new permission level to the group "My Approvers"

c) Someone should have delete permission - the creator owner?? And the admin should have some permissions, otherwise in case of an error the item is "lost in space"